# Drupal equivalent for Java?

Tags: java, content-management-system

i wonder if there is a Drupal equivalent for Java users?

they have open source CMS alternatives?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are. You can find [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Java_2) an overview of them all, the popular ones being [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/), [Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.org), [Magnolia](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/home.html) and [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/). You can pick and compare at [CMS Matrix](http://cmsmatrix.org).

This question is also already asked a several times here in SO. Check the tags [`[java]+[cms]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+cms).

Comment: Liferay is in no way equivalent to Drupal.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan care to share why you said that? I'm a java developer and I dont want to work with drupal, what is wrong with Liferay?

Comment: @Lrrr: Neil just overgeneralized "CMS" as "Drupal".

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of [open-source Java CMS](http://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+java+cms)es.

I've never personally used any, but there certainly are a lot of them out there.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Java_2) is another list, on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jahia](http://www.jahia.com/),
An open-source Java CMS which offers a Java alternative to Drupal. The Jahia community is, of course, not as big as the Drupal one but they give you answers!

Answer (score 0):

Word *"CMS"* in Java & PHP world has significant difference of meaning, (difference of scale). I don't remember Java CMS ready to work in half of hour.

Drupal (in PHP world) comparing to other CSM applications, is one step more oriented to reusable "component" organisation (very, very specific, with own idea of "virtual methods", component events, lifecycle - if someone understand that is possible OOP in raw C, understand that "drupal has component philosophy"). 
Over "component philosophy" next layer builds management of content too. Good idea of general architecture, fatal realised in ugly coding standards / coding convention.
Others PHP CMS (Joomla andn clones, Wordpres blogging) are oriented more direct to content (~= for endusers).

In Java world most cited here CMS are very big, can say fat, with huge content repositories, with programmers API hidden to programmers (paradox: open source but hidden in multilayer, multimodule philosophy. Beginning programmer cannot be productive in many months of learning. Many have ancient (JPS etc) architecture.). Content repositories are so huge, designed for biggest libraries, government, corporations, usually have build-in one of the best searchers (90% from Lucene family).

Return to question: if someone has positive associations with drupal capability to add own components suggest in Java world look at *portlet containers* (Liferay, Jbos, jetspedd probably retired). I guess, have similar freedom to add independent "squares of content".

But when required is orientation to content (ready to go), all high positioned and cited here: akfresco, opencms. With disclaimer: learning curve in normal content management is heavier that in PHP-CMS, software is free, but You can buy support & learning in case of problems ;)

Pay attention to applications not named CMS: good wiki servers (open XWiki?, commercial Confluence). usually have much more features than expected of most PHP wikis - have plugin philosophy, can include totally different segments of content etc.

Hosting cost in java & PHP is generally known ;) Safety of code, refactoring too. Java don't give guarantee of high quality (i.e. spaghetti code exist in JSP like in PHP), but usually forces better design.